# Azman on a resource level

Tags: c#, authorization, azman

I have used [Azman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx) in a previous project and it works well when authorizing operations on a system-level

- authorize role **X** to perform operation **Y**.
- allow **Managers** to **update_sales_orders**

In a new project, I need to manage authorizations on a record level.

- authorize role **X** to perform operation **Y** on record **#Z**
- allow **Managers** to **update_sales_order** # **23**

What is the best way of achieving this?  If there is an authorization API that supports this I would be glad to hear about it.  Otherwise, any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AzMan has a feature called [scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757868%28WS.10%29.aspx)
that can accomplish what you are asking. A scope can be any piece of data. Here at work, for example, we have a branch scope. So, for a person assigned to a scope of 1234, that person can only perform the operations assigned to them on data belonging to branch 1234.

Comment: It appears that you need to create a LOT of scopes if you are using it for row level security or am I miss understanding scopes?

Comment: Yes, potentially, unless you have something more generic that you can group things by. We have some applications with 100s of branch scopes which can hurt performance, but we can group those into business entities such as a Division that rolls up several branches into a single entity.

Comment: Scopes seems to be the answer to my question. But I really need to measure the performance degradation when having thousands of scopes before going ahead.